# Getting the GUID of a VS 2008 tool window

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, macros

Does anybody have a short code sample that can be run in the VS macro editor on how to enumerate the tool windows in VS 2008 and show the GUID for each one?

Or do you know another way to find this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enumerate the child keys under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ToolWindows

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing, though I did it manually.  :(  It seems like there should be a way to do it in a macro, though, since you already have access to at least some of the tool windows through macros.